# Proof of the Contour Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

---

A couple days ago I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237599/what-is-the-meaning-of-dz-in-complex-integrals) concerning complex integrals

The person that answered explained to me that the integral of the contour $C$ defined by $γ(t),a≤t≤b$ $ $ can be written as follows

$\int_Cf(z)dz$ (about $C$) is equal to the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of

$f(z_1)[z_1-z_0] + f(z_2)[z_2-z_1] + ... + f(z_n)[z_n-z_{n-1}]$

where $z_n = γ(t_n)$, $a = t_0<t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n=b$

---

The issue with the latter is that it implies that if all the $z_j-z_{j-1}$ tend to $0$, we will get the same result. I suppose this assumption is correct, but I haven´t been able to find any proof on the internet

If someone could direct me to or show me the most clear proof you know I would truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some informal, notional thoughts. For a rigorous treatment you can see the text of [Alfhors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070006571).

We first need to assume the contour is rectifiable, which is to say it can be assigned an arc length. If the parameterization $t \mapsto \gamma(t)$ is given then it is possible to write
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt. 
$$
The definition of the complex integral thus follows from that of the real integral. The rectifiability of $\gamma$ is needed to ensure good behavior for the measure $dz = \gamma'(t)dt$.

To see how this is equivalent to your definition, recall how the real integral (of Riemann) can be defined as a limit of Riemann sums calculated over successive refinements of the partitions of $[a,b]$. Clearly each partition of $[a,b]$ induces a partition of the contour by setting $\gamma(p)$ as a member of the contour partition whenever $p$ is a member of the partition of $[a,b]$. As the Riemann sum approaches the integral, each $\gamma(p)$ asymptotically approaches a straight line which connects its endpoints $z_j$ and $z_{j-1}$. In the limit of an infinitely refined partition these two will be identical (assuming again that $\gamma$ is rectifiable), and thus the definitions coincide.

Comment: Right, from that equality one is able to treat the complex integral (somewhat) as real and 'prove' the formula. However, in that question I mentioned, the proof provided requires that we assume that as long as all the intervals tend to 0 we will get the same result.

Comment: What I meant with the last comment is that I´m in need of understanding the formula to prove that equality you just wrote, so using that equality to prove the formula would be circular.

Comment: If you want to prove the definition in terms of a real valued integral in terms of the definition which uses a partition of the contour, you have to accept the latter as a definition.